# Pass window object to Backbone/Marionette AMD app

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, marionette

I am working on a large Zend based php app that maintains its session based on every page request that renews the frontend JavaScript setTimout based variable. This is not a backend stored session var but rather a front end setTimeout javaSctipt var that expires after certain time and gets renewed on every php page request. After I implemented layer on top of Zend I am having issues accessing this variable in my Backbone/Marionette top layer to keep session in sync. I've tried attaching it to the window but once Backbone/Marionette hits the router and does fetch on its REST api call I do lose all previous references to the window. I am trying to pass this js stored timeout var from my php call to Backbone/Marionette router but once I hit Marionette router I lose all previous references to the window object. My question is how do I access this SESSIONREMAINDER global in my Backbone/Marionette AMD based app when I hit the router from my php action. It looks I lose that window object

**globalscripts.js** (file included in every php request living in some header template)

legacy code that I can't change but need access to in my top layer

> ```
> var SESSIONREMAINDER;
> ```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function () {
    var nativeSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;

    window.bindTimeout = function (listener, interval) {
        function setTimeout(code, delay) {
            var elapsed = 0,
                h;

            h = window.setInterval(function () {
                    elapsed += interval;
                    if (elapsed < delay) {
                        listener(delay - elapsed);
                    } else {
                        window.clearInterval(h);
                    }
                }, interval);
            return nativeSetTimeout(code, delay);
        }

        window.setTimeout = setTimeout;
        setTimeout._native = nativeSetTimeout;
    };
    }());
    window.bindTimeout(function (t) {
        console.log(t + "ms remaining");
        SESSIONREMAINDER = t;
    }, 10000);      

    var sessionTimeout = window.setTimeout("ModalOverlay.open('/two/phase2/echo2.0/countdown.htm', 400, 300, 'Session Expiration')",2400000);
    this 
});
```

SingupformController.php (Zend Controller Action that hits Marionette router)

> public function editdraftAction() {

```
    $formId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_id');
    $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/form/#id/' . $formId;
    $this->_redirect($url);
}
```

**main.js** (config and shims for all libs) this is where I need access to my previously set window.sessionTimeout

config

> require.config({
>       baseURL: 'assets/js',

```
paths: {
    jquery: '../../components/jquery/jquery',  // amd version
    jqueryui: '../../components/jquery-ui-1.10.0/ui/jquery-ui',  // amd version
    underscore: '../../components/underscore-amd/underscore', // amd version
    underscoreM: 'libs/underscore/underscore-mustache',  // underscore templating supporting mustache style {{ ... }}
    moment: 'libs/moment/moment.min',  // underscore templating supporting mustache style {{ ... }}
    mustache: '../../components//mustache.js-master/mustache',  // mustache templating {{ ... }}
    backbone: '../../components/backbone-amd/backbone', // amd version
    'backbone.wreqr': '../../components/backbone.wreqr/lib/amd/backbone.wreqr', // amd version
    'backbone.eventbinder': '../../components/backbone.eventbinder/lib/amd/backbone.eventbinder', // amd version
    'backbone.babysitter': '../../components/backbone.babysitter/lib/amd/backbone.babysitter', // amd version
    'backbone.validation': '../../components/backbone.validation-master/src/backbone-validation', // non amd version
    'backbone.relational': '../../components/backbone.relational/backbone-relational', // non amd version
    'backbone.session': '../../components/backbone.session/backbone.session', 
    bbmodal: '../../components/backbone.bootstrap.modal/src/backbone.bootstrap-modal',
    modelbinder: '../../components/backbone.modelbinder/Backbone.ModelBinder', // amd version
    backstack: '../../components/backstack-master/backstack',
    marionette: '../../components/marionette/lib/core/amd/backbone.marionette',  // amd version
    //marionette: '../../components/marionette/lib/core/amd/backbone.marionette.v0.9.12',  // amd version
    bootstrap: '../../components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap', 
    //dr: '../../components/dr/dr.jquery.plugin',
    text: '../../components/requirejs-text/text',
    domReady:'../../components/requirejs-domready/domReady',
    colorpicker: '../../components/jquery/plugins/colorpicker/colorpicker',  // amd version
    notifier: '../../components/backbone.notifier/js/backbone.notifier',  // amd version
    'jquery.spinner': '../../components/jquery/plugins/spin/jquery.spinner', 
    'jquery.cookie': '../../components/jquery/plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie', 
    spin: '../../components/jquery/plugins/spin/spin', // amd version
    utils: '../../components/utils/'
},

shim: {     
    bootstrap: ['jquery'],
    jqueryui: ['jquery'],
    colorpicker: ['jquery'],
    spin: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'Spinner'
    },

    'jquery.spinner':{
        deps:['jquery', 'spin'],
        exports: 'jqspinner'
    },

    bbmodal: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone']
    },        

    dr: ['jquery'],

    'backbone.relational' : {
        deps: ['underscore','backbone']
    }
}
```

});

and startApp (both of these are part of same main, js I just broke it in two pieces since the codeblock had strange preview

> require([
>       'app', 
>       'jquery',
>       'jqueryui', 
>       'domReady', 
>       'utils/debug',
>       'controllers/signupformcontroller', 
>       'controllers/formbuilderrouter', 
>       'controllers/secondapp'], 
>       startApp);

```
function startApp(
        App, 
        $, 
        jqueryui, 
        domReady,
        DebugUtils,
        signupFormController, 
        formBuilderRouter, 
        secondApp) {
'use strict';

var options = {
    secondApp: secondApp,
    formBuilderRouter: formBuilderRouter,       
    signupFormController: signupFormController
}; 

$(function() {
    DebugUtils.log('Main App.start(options)');
    DebugUtils.log(options);
    App.start(options);    
});
```

};

My question is how do I access global SESSIONREMAINDER once I hit my index.html that looks like this

> 

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Signup Form Builder</title>    
    <meta name="description" content="Backbone Marionette Modular RequireJS 2.0 Bootstrap Responsive">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="components/jquery-ui-1.10.0/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/form-main2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/form-designer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/dr-stylesheet-ff-compressed.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/form-builder.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load assets/js/main.js after require.js loads. -->
    <script  data-main="assets/js/main" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

    <!-- only dependency to require since we don't have it AMD enabled and need cross browser commmunication on app initialization -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/legacy.support/json/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/porthole/porthole.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
    <iframe id="surveyframe" name="surveyframe" frameborder="0" src="/builder/proxies/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I can post more code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies but, please provide a code specific question; this wall of text presents a pretty broad question.

Comment: Thanks for providing code +1, Although you might now get more answers by re-posting (so it appears at the top of the list) and closing this. Sorry.